# Drywall Repair in Ceiling

Tags: drywall

My contractor replaced a section of a ceiling with a new section of drywall (about 2' x 3'), he then built a floor to ceiling closet which
covered most of the repaired area.
The entire section was neither mudded nor taped.

Is this acceptable ?

Comment: Are there untaped seams in the closet? If so, this is not standard.

Comment: The answer depends on your contract. Was it stipulated that all surfaces would be finished?

Answer (score 3):

Where I work, living spaces are taped and mudded. Garages typically just get tape. Your vicinity might vary.

More importantly, though, did you have a contract with any specifics about the work to be done? If you have paper, then you'll probably get the job finished.

If you don't, you're probably going to have a bit of a struggle to get it done. If you haven't made the final payment, you've got a bit of leverage.